# How to align D3 circles on semicircle

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I have a semi circle that I need to align Radios I created from circles. The number of radios will be dynamic and will need to keep them centered. Here is what I currently have.

UPDATE, just realized that the 2 screenshots can be confusing. The order of the radios are not the same. Ignore that. I just need the alignment to be correct,

[image: CURRENT PROGRESS]

This is the desired result.

[image: DESIRED RESULT]

I have a working demo here
[WORKING DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-d3-pie-chart-forked-4e0f3?file=/src/PieHooks.js)

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand you. Please try `innerRadius(INNER_RADIUS-1) .outerRadius(INNER_RADIUS);` instead of  `.innerRadius(radiusArcRadios - 9)
      .outerRadius(radiusArcRadios - 10);` for the arcRadios

Comment: @enxaneta I just made a update to the post. if that was the confusion

Comment: The semi circle isnt the problem. that is aligned correctly. I need the radios to align on that arc

Comment: How should the centering work if there are an even number of radios?

Comment: @backtick just spaced out evenly on the arch

Comment: there doesnt have to be radios at the end of both sides of the arch. I can change the size of the arch based on the number of radios or It can be as is. not very picky at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [backtick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537763/5768908) is a beautiful math explanation, you can do that with a simple mix of [`getPointAtLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getPointAtLength) and [`getTotalLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength):

First you do...

```
const arcPathLength = arcPath.node().getTotalLength() / 2;
```

... where `arcPath` is just that gray arc the radio buttons will follow. Here I'm dividing the length by 2 because the arc goes back to the origin. Then you just do:

```
svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(RADIO_DATA)
    //etc...
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => arcPath.node().getPointAtLength((arcPathLength/(RADIO_DATA.length - 1)) * i).x)
    .attr("cy", (d, i) => arcPath.node().getPointAtLength((arcPathLength/(RADIO_DATA.length - 1)) * i).y)
```

Since I cannot fork the code without logging in, here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Adjust the texts accordingly. Also, pay attention to the fact that circle elements have no `d` or `text` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Given your preferred arc angle A and number of points N, find the angular distance between each point:

`PA = A / (N - 1)`.

Next, find the angle described by a vertical line from the circle's center and the point we're calculating.

Initial observations:

- The largest possible value of this angle is `A / 2`
- The smallest possible value is `PA / 2` if N is even, `0` if N is odd.
- The angle changes in increments of PA

Counting points away from the center (X), we can describe the angle using terms we've defined:

`A / 2 - PA * (floor(N / 2) - X)`

For the examples directly below, X is 1 and 2 respectively.

[image]

Assuming:

- A = 90° (not depicted accurately)
- N = 4

From which follows:

- PA = 30°

Plugging in these values, we get:

`45 - 30 * (floor(2) - 1) = 15`

and

`45 - 30 * (floor(2) - 2) = 45`

Now that we have the angle `a`, we can use trigonometry (specifically [SOH-CAH-TOA](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SOHCAHTOA.html)) to find the x and y offsets of the point relative to the center.

Note that because the points to the left of the plumb line are mirror images of their counterparts to the right, you need only to negate the x-offset from the center to get the locations of the left-hand points.

[Update: Here's a simpler (but still math-based) implementation.](https://observablehq.com/@mattspalmer/distributed-points-on-an-arc)

[image]